# Keycloak: Can I set the idle session timeout per client auth request?

Tags: spring-boot, openid-connect, keycloak

## Scenario:

We have our custom IDP(Spring Boot) and 2-3 clients(Spring Boot) in Keycloak. We're letting users authenticate through OIDC flow.
**Keycloak SSO Session Idle:** 30 Minutes(Default)
**Client 1:** Session Expiry > 45 Minutes
**Client 2:** Session Expiry > 15 Minutes

## Problem:

- When Client 1 gets login their session expiry should be set to 45 minutes, but after 30 minutes idle screen it gets logout
- When Client 2 gets login their session expiry should be set to 15 minutes. After 15 minutes client session gets killed from a client app server but it still presents in keycloak. So till 30 minutes session is still present in keycloak. And if we hit URL we get logged in.

## Question:

Can we set session expiry as per the client's request? Or in another way can we override keycloak SSO Session Idle through auth request or through API?

We simply want to use the client's session expiry/timeout.

Comment: Did you figure this out, or did you end up using multiple realms?